# how to protect a website in elastic beanstalk docker nginx using password

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, docker, elastic-beanstalk

I've a django web application hosted in AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Docker and Nginx. I am using supervisor to start nginx and uwsgi. Need to protect it the website using password. I've tried using `.htaccess`.

```
htpasswd -cb /etc/nginx/.htpasswd admin admin
```

and added the nginx config with

```
location / {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  uwsgi_pass unix:/var/sockets/api.sock;
  include    /home/docker/uwsgi_params; 
}
```

It's working but its asking password repeatedly. Usually htaccess only asks password once in session. But it asks for username and password every time we click one field or button. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to log in or 'asking password repeatedly' means the box pops immediately back? In the latter, authentication mechanism kicks in, but you are not providind a recognized password. The auth_basic module follows the 'HTTP Basic Authentication' protocol, which is probably the same behind Apache's auth too, which simply consists in sending an 'Authorization' header with the 'user:password' duple encoded in Base64. Check the auth file is where it is supposed to be, contains user/password information understandable by nginx, and that you are using correct user/password to log in.

Comment: found the error it was not reloated to the nginx config but wiht the django app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057631/nginx-password-authentication-keeps-prompting-for-password

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question, providing details so yo ucould help other people having the same problem as yourself. Editing/Rephrasing the question might also help correctly referencing it, since it has nothing to do with nginx.

Comment: @BernardRosset it has connection to nginx. Basic authentication uses the Authorization header to transmit user and password. Django REST also uses this header in the TokenAuthentication authentication backend. Nginx does not support multiple Authorization headers, so if you try to login and use Token authentication simultaneously it wont work.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the original question + once again *not* related to nginx. You should have done your homework since there are already several questions about sending multiple HTTP Authorization headers (or several token in a single one) on multiple StackExchange websites. nginx usually follows HTTP standards so in case of doubt, make sure you document yourself properly. Namely, [RFC7235, section 3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1) provides you with the standard process to submit multiple credentials token. Multiple HTTP Authorization header are not standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all the issue was same as in the following question
. It seems they have a solution for it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057631/nginx-password-authentication-keeps-prompting-for-password